If uniformly over $n$, $P(A_{n,k}) \to 0 $ then also uniformly over $n$ $E[|X| 1_{A_{n,k}}] \to 0 $?
Suppose one has a family of measurable sets $A_{n,k}$, $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$ on a prob. space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ such that
$ P(A_{n,k}) \leq 1/k $ and an integrable random variable $X$, i.e. $E[|X|] < \infty$. I want to see if the equation
\begin{equation}
\lim_{k \to \infty} \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E[|X| 1_{A_{n,k}} ]  = 0 
\end{equation}
holds ?
For each fixed $n$ this is clear, using e.g. the dominated convergence theorem. But I assume this also holds uniformly, since the sets $A_{n,k}$ also have uniform (over $n$) bound on their sizes, but I can't put together a good argument for it.

$E|X|<\infty$ implies that given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $E|X| 1_E<\epsilon$ whenever $P(E) <\delta$. Your result is immediate from this.

ah yes, that seems to be the part of measure theory that I had missed, thanks !
